# How to ensure markers dont get cut-off in jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I am utilizing `jqPlot` to create a linear chart with a Y axis from 0% to 100%. The problem I am having is that one of the values falls on the X axis (is 0%) or 100% it is getting cut-off by the axis or the border of the chart.

How can I ensure this does not happen, while keeping the Y axis minimum at 0% and the max at 100%?

Comment: I think the "pad" attribute is supposed to give the margin you need to prevent point cut-off (seen at http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html), but setting that attribute is not working for me, either. :/

Comment: Has anyone got a fix to this? Please help..!!

Comment: no one has answered it anywhere... still struggling with the bad aesthetics of it

Answer (score 0):

there is a `pad` factor that can be set for `axesDefaults` like this

```
axesDefaults: {
    pad: 1.1,
}
```

or it can be set for individual axes like this

```
axes:{
    xaxis:{
        label: 'X-Axis Label',
        pad: 2,
    },
    yaxis:{
        label: 'Y-Asix Label',
        pad: 1.1,
    }
},
```

where the value is a **factor** multiplied by the data range on the axis to give the axis range so that data points don't fall on the edges of the axis.

as described here:
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html

Comment: This is for the axis. The problem I am having is on data drawn in the charts.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle / image to explain what you mean?